# Table control empty after changing screen attributes

Tags: abap, dynpro

I am fetching and displaying data in table control. If I don't change the column attribute then it is displayed fine with the data. All columns are input enabled by default.

However, if I try to change it; no data is displayed. In debug, data is present in the table.

The below code is written in the change_col_attr module. What am I missing?

```
 IF p_screen-screen-name IN lr_invisible. "range containing fields
    p_screen-screen-active = 0.
    p_screen-screen-invisible = 1.
    p_screen-invisible = 1.
  ELSEIF p_screen-screen-name IN lr_inactive.
    p_screen-screen-active = 0.
    p_screen-screen-invisible = 0.
  ELSE.
    p_screen-screen-active = 1.
    p_screen-screen-invisible = 0.

  ENDIF.
'''
```

Comment: Is the change_col_attr module a PBO or PAI module? The code should also be surrounded by loop at screen

Comment: It is in the pbo and is surrounded by loop at. I am calling the above code in a routine in that loop since I need to have multiple logic for multiple users.